# firefox extension load javascript file

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I have a firefox extension and I loaded an external javascript file to access some file writing functions. It works on Windows Vista but not on Windows 7. My code for loading the javascript file is this:

```
onLoad: function() {
// initialization code
this.initialized = true;
this.strings = document.getElementById("bs-strings");
var service = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/moz/jssubscript-loader;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.mozIJSSubScriptLoader);service.loadSubScript("chrome://global/content/writefunc.js");

},
```

I tried to find the path were my extension is saved under Windows 7 but could not find it. My guess is that Firefox plus extensions are installed differently under Windows 7 and I cannot find the file if I declare the path like I did. Are there better ways to load javascript files in extension?

Comment: Is the version of FF same in both the windows machines?....If yes which is the version...else try changing the version to the one in which its working properly...

Comment: `writefunc.js` is a file provided by you or by Firefox? If by you, then the path should probably be: `chrome://<yourAddonNameHere>/content/writefunc.js`.

Comment: @1 Versions are 3.6.15 on both.                                       @2 Ok I'll try that.

Comment: on my win7 machine this is the path to extensions: c:\Users\someusername\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\profilename\extensions\ but based on your last paragraph I would suspect your chrome.manifest can you show it to us? Also if writefunc.js is your function you should probably consider using it as JavaScript module instead of using jssubscript loader

Comment: Hi,

I found the problem. I installed an extension which used functions of this javascript. So I had already access to these functions but I didn't install it on my other computer and the path was wrong:

chrome://<yourAddonNameHere>/content/writefunc.js

did it. Thanks for support.

Comment: @Felix Kling - you should put your comment as answer and user366121 should mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`writefunc.js` is a file provided by you or by Firefox?

If by you, then the path has to point to *your* plugin:

```
chrome://<yourAddonNameHere>/content/writefunc.js
```